# Access LibreOffice Autotext templates from command line

Tags: libreoffice

I want to use the Autotext templates from the command line. The location are this:

```
%APPDATA%\LibreOffice\4\user\autotext\mytexts.bau

C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\share\autotext\en-US\template.bau

C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\share\autotext\en-US\standard.bau

C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\share\autotext\en-US\crdbus50.bau
```

I'm trying to access that file without success. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "use" them from the command line?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket access to the content for example of the "Lorem Ipsum" to use it in a Powershell script

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket no error at all I just don't even know what to try to read the content of that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are compressed archives that use standard ZIP compression algorithms.

First, decompress them using any ZIP decompression tool, such as 7-Zip or Peazip.

When you decompress the archives, the output will be readable.

From the command line, you can view the contents of any of the output files by using the command shell's integrated `type` command.

For example, to view the `BlockList.xml` that was extracted from the archive `%APPDATA%\LibreOffice\4\user\autotext\mytexts.bau`, use the command:

`type %APPDATA%\LibreOffice\4\user\autotext\BlockList.xml`

If you want the command shell to pause after each screenful of text, you can pipe through the `more` command, like this:

`type %APPDATA%\LibreOffice\4\user\autotext\BlockList.xml | more`

Comment: Great! Now... how did you know (or deduct) that it was a compressed file?

Comment: @ranemirusG The first 4 bytes of the file (in hex) are `50` `4B` `03` `04`.  This is one of the 3 possible signatures of a ZIP-compressed file.